# Looping structure and reusing EntityNew

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I just recently got to start using ORM so be prepared for this to be an easy answer...

So I've striped out any error checking and defining of parameters, et al.  This is the part of the code that is Adding a user to the database.  The entity is being populated correctly, everything is working, except!  I am getting the exact same record inserted thousands of times.  If I replace the Entity ORM code with a writeOutput, I get what is expected but with the orm added back in it becomes a, practically, endless loop and never updates the entity values.  I imagine it's a conceptual short coming on my part.
Thoughts?

```
    companyObj = EntityLoadByPK( 'companyInfo', companyId );
    for(i=1; i LTE application._.size(toCommit); i = i++ ){
        /**Again, error checking and defining parameters were pulled out for clarity.  
        It's all about the ORM.[I've got to assume]*/

        structClear(currentEntity);
        StructClear( toSaveObjects );

        currentUserName = structFind(toCommit[i],'USERNAME');
        currentEntity = EntityNew( "CompanyUsers");
        currentEntity.setCompanyId(companyObj);

        try{
            properties = getMetaData(currentEntity).properties;
            for(t=1; t <= arrayLen(properties); t++){
                property        = properties[t];
                currentField    = #property.Name#;
                if( StructkeyExists(toCommit[i],property.name)){
                    currentSetValue = structFind(toCommit[i],property.name);
                    if( LEN( TRIM( currentSetValue ) ) ){
                        if( ListFindNoCase( listOfKeys, TRIM( currentField ), "," ) ){
                            if( ListFindNoCase( toCommitOwnFunction, TRIM( currentField ), "," ) ){
                                <! ---[] Requires separate fuction --->
                                if(currentField eq 'userGroups'){
                                    groupObj = EntityLoadByPK( 'companyGroups', 1);
                                    entity_groupObject = EntityNew('companyUsers_J_companyGroups');
                                    entity_groupObject.setUserId(currentEntity);
                                    entity_groupObject.setGroupId(groupObj);
                                }
                            } else{
                                /***BTW, the duplication occurs even if the fields values aren't assigned dynamically.*/
                                evaluate("currentEntity." & "set#property.name#(currentSetValue)");
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };
            };

            transaction {
                EntitySave(currentEntity);
                if(IsDefined('groupObj')){
                    EntitySave(groupObj);
                };
                transactionCommit();
            };
            committedData.message[i]    = TRIM( mssgQualifier ) & TRIM( mssgValue );
        }
        catch(any e){
            committedData.message[i]    = TRIM( mssgQualifier ) & ' failed.  No further information is available.';
        }
    }
    return committedData;
};
```

So I've tried to clean up the above code.  I also came across OrmEvictEntity which resolves the primary issue I was having.

```
private function commitStruct( required any toCommit, required string toCommitOwnFunction, string shrtName, any companyId ){

    // Struct Key List.  May vary by record
    var listOfKeys              = '';
    // ORM object to save.  Create for clearing at loop head
    var currentEntity           = structNew();
    // anncillary/related obcts to save with entity
    var entityObjsToSave        = structNew();
    // The temp subject of the return msg
    var msgSubject              = '';
    // The temp action of the return msg
    var msgAction               = '';           
    // committed data struct
    var committed               = structNew();
    // msgSubject and msgAction return struct
    var committed.returnMsg     = structNew();
    // holds the model object properties
    var properties              = structNew();
    //current row username, if applicable
    var currentUserName         = '';

    // if entity required companyId relationship
    if( ListFindNoCase( this.typeNeedsCompId, shrtName) ){
        var companyObj = EntityLoadByPK( 'companyInfo', companyId );
    };          

    // If we are Adding Users (AU), create the entity and get bean metadata
    if( ListFindNoCase( 'AU,UU', TRIM( shrtName ), ',' , false ) ) {
        currentEntity = EntityNew( "CompanyUsers" );
        properties = getMetaData( currentEntity ).properties;
    }

    //toCommit Counter
    i=0;
//------------[START] Primary 'row' loop -------------
    for( row IN toCommit ){
        i++;

        //drop into row var
        row = toCommit[i];              

        // clear primaries--Future Use.
        structClear( entityObjsToSave );
        currentUserName = '';
        msgSubject      = '';
        msgAction       = '';

        //Update listOfKeys for this record
        listOfKeys  = StructKeyList(toCommit[i]);

        //assign username for frequent, future reference
        if( ListFindNoCase(listOfKeys, 'USERNAME' ) ){
            currentUserName = structFind( row, 'USERNAME' );
        }

        // If we are Adding Users (AU) or Updating Users (UU), create the entity and assign default msg values
        if(shrtName eq 'AU'){                   
            ORMEvictEntity("CompanyUsers");
            currentEntity   = EntityNew( "CompanyUsers" );
            msgSubject  = TRIM( currentUserName );
            msgAction       = ' - submitted successfully';
        }

        properties = getMetaData( currentEntity ).properties;
    //------------[START] FUTURE CONDITIONS -------------

    //.------------[END] FUTURE CONDITIONS -------------

        // Set companyId to entity
        if( ListFindNoCase( this.typeNeedsCompId, shrtName ) ){
            currentEntity.setCompanyId( companyObj );
        };
        try{

        //------------[START] Looping items in row -------------
            for( property IN properties ){
                currentField    = setFieldNameAndValue( property, row, listOfKeys );
                //if this field was not ruled out for some reason previously but caught locally
                if( currentField.fieldValue NEQ 'IGNORE' ){
                    // if the field name is listed in toCommitOwnFunction, split off for separate processing
                    if( ListFindNoCase( toCommitOwnFunction, TRIM( currentField.fieldName ), "," ) ){
                        // test toCommitOwnFunction field names
                        switch (currentField.fieldName){
                            case 'userGroups':
                                    if( isDefined( 'groupObj' ) ){
                                        ORMEvictEntity('groupObj');
                                    }
                                    if( isDefined( 'entity_groupObject' ) ){
                                        ORMEvictEntity("entity_groupObject");
                                    };
                                    groupObj            = EntityLoad( 'companyGroups', { groupName = #currentField.fieldValue# });
                                    entity_groupObject  = EntityNew('companyUsers_J_companyGroups');
                                    entity_groupObject.setUserId(currentEntity);
                                    entity_groupObject.setGroupId(groupObj);
                                    break;
                            default:
                                msgAction = '-Error.  Unexpected Field';
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                        if( LEN(TRIM(currentField.fieldValue))){
                            //Simple field type insertion
                            evaluate( "currentEntity." & "set#currentField.fieldName#( currentField.fieldValue )" );
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        //.------------[END] Looping items in row -------------

            transaction {
                EntitySave(currentEntity);
                if( !isNull( entity_groupObject ) ){
                    EntitySave( entity_groupObject );
                };
                transactionCommit();
            };
            committed.returnMsg[i] = TRIM( msgSubject ) & TRIM( msgAction );
        }               
        catch(any e){
            committed.returnMsg[i] = TRIM( msgSubject ) & ' - Action Failed.  No additional information is available.<br/><br/>' & e;               }
    }
//.------------[END] Primary 'row' loop -------------
    return committed;
};
```

My remaining issue is the groupObj, simply due to my lack of ORM experience I'm sure.
I have cfcs for CompanyUsers with a one-to-many being expressed in companyUsers_J_companyGroups and CompanyGroups with same (back to companyUsers_J_companyGroups).  companyUsers_J_companyGroups has many-to-one pointed back out to CompanyUsers and CompanyGroups -

```
    property name='userId'
            fieldtype='id,many-to-one'
            displayname='userId'
            cfc='companyUsers'
            fkcolumn='userId'
            hint='The user side of the relationship';
property name='groupId'
            fieldtype='id,many-to-one'
            displayname='groupId'
            cfc='companygroups'
            fkcolumn='groupId'
            hint='The group side of the user/group relationship';
```

I continue to get errors on the group processing.

Comment: 1. I would use for-in loops just to make it clearer. 2. currentEntity is always a CompanyUsers entity. I don't think there is a need to getMetaData() over and over. I would just store that in a variable. 3. All you are doing is committing groupObj. I would focus on getting that thing good data. I would probably `writedump` just before `EntitySave` 4. I am seeing 5 ifs nested I come up with a simpler approach or make a function to deal with this

Comment: @JamesAMohler - 1. I agree, thanks. 2.currentEntity will ultimately be dynamic though referencing it once per certainly makes sense.3.it's to be taken care of after the primary issue but again, I agree so thanks. 4. I pulled those in from a few locals just to demonstrate. you're right, it's not the least bit clean. 4 for 4! :)
The writeDump of the entity of the currentEntity dumps the same, first record, over and over.
My assumption was that there is an issue with trying to reuse the same entity.  Do you know if that could be the problem?

Comment: I think there is an issue with how you are looping, but it is hard to untangle what should exist and when it should exist.

Comment: @JamesAMohler  Thanks James.  I'll try to strip it bare and post.

Comment: Keep your original code and just append the edited version afterward. It might make the question long, but it will help a future person understand the process by which the problem was solved.

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Thank again for your input, I was avoiding time on clean code in  case I needed to take an entirely different tack.  In cleaning, I mostly resolved the issue.  I know that 'Clean Code' is necessarily 'Answer' worthy but in  this case, is was.  My remaining minor issue, solely due to my lack of ORM experience, is the groupObj issue.  Which I will go ahead and include in an addendum to the post.  If it's not the correct approach please inform and I'll repost where/how it should be posted.  Thanks again.

Comment: You should write up an answer. Explain how to covers most of concerns. Point how it is not perfect. Next person who has a similar issue will be a better position to solve their problems. If at a late date you want to re address this, make a new question. On SO, as long as your questions are good, you have an unlimited amount of questions you can ask.

Comment: Also, asking a question and post answer to you own question if perfectly OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue with coming to this solution,  that I had, was that the CF parser's requirements (re: #'s, evaluate, and so) seemed counterintuitive. I'm not a big fan of 'evaluate' to begin with.  Regardless, the following resolves the issue.  Outstanding is maintaining relational entities to be followed up in a separate post.

```
        private function commitStruct( required any toCommit, required string toCommitOwnFunction, string shrtName, any companyId ){

        // ORM object to save.  Create for clearing at loop head
        var currentEntity= structNew();

        // committed data struct
        var committed   = structNew();

        // holds the model object properties
        var properties  = structNew();

        // Create default entity object and metadata
        currentEntity   = EntityNew( "CompanyUsers" );
        properties      = getMetaData( currentEntity ).properties;

        //toCommit Counter
        i = 0;

    //------------[START] Primary 'row' loop -------------
        for( row IN toCommit ){

            i++;

            //drop into row var
            row = toCommit[i];

            // Here we are Evicting the entity for reuse.
            ORMEvictEntity("CompanyUsers");

            //create the entity 
            currentEntity   = EntityNew( "CompanyUsers" );

            //getting the cfc column setup and properties
            properties      = getMetaData( currentEntity ).properties;

            try{
                //------------[START] Looping items in row -------------
                for( property IN properties ){
                    //assign the fieldname 
                    current.fieldName   = #property.Name#;
                    //assign the fieldvalue to appropriate var, current.fieldValue
                    current.fieldValue = structFind( row, current.fieldName );

                    // Simple field type insertion, meaning one-to-many, many-to-many, et al would need
                    // to be split off and handled differently.
                    evaluate( "currentEntity." & "set#currentField.fieldName#( currentField.fieldValue )" );

                };
                //.------------[END] Looping items in row -------------

                transaction {

                    // Save the entity
                    EntitySave(currentEntity);

                    transactionCommit();
                };
            }
            catch(any e){
                writeDump(e);
            }
        }
    //.------------[END] Primary 'row' loop -------------
    };
```

Many thanks to @James A Mohler for all of his advice.